Using TABLE keyword to SELECT everything from vs SELECT * from table_name
I was going through Mysql Official documentation 8.0 and here Mysql Documentation 5.6.6 Using Foreign Keys I found that we can use TABLE keyword to select everything instead of using SELECT.
Can anybody explain what is difference?

I wondered about the motivation for introducing this but according to the release notes it ("table clauses") is a SQL standard feature https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-19.html#mysqld-8-0-19-sql-syntax

The documentation indicates that TABLE yourtable selects all rows from said table. Hence, it is equivalent to SELECT * FROM yourtable, but you cannot filter using a where clause, so TABLE yourtable is a syntactic sugar to selecting everything on that table, but will not allow column projection, column aliasing and filtering.

"The documentation" - what documentation? Seems to be missing a link to where this is documented https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/table.html - some limited filtering is possible via ORDER BY ... LIMIT ... OFFSET

@MartinSmith thanks for pointing that out. Added the link accordingly.

@Lajos Arpad Thanks for pointing me, In general meaning was clear to me. I will read about it.

@NabeelBhatti happy to help
